# Mapping optional to many relationship in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Some background: I inherited the database. Other applications are running against it, so I can't change the structure. We have a table of employees and a table of activities. Some of the employees are supervisors and the activities can optionally have a supervisor specified to indicate that only that particular supervisor can have their employees work that particular activity.

The way the database is set up, an employee is a supervisor if the SupID field is not null and that is the field that the SupID column in Activity refers to.

Here's a sample of the classes I'm working with:

```
public class Emp
{
    public int EmpID { get; set; }
    public string Fname { get; set; }
    public string Lname { get; set; }
    public int SupID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Activity> SupervisedActivities { get; set; }
}

public class Activity
{
    [Key]
    public string ActNum { get; set; }
    public int SupID { get; set; }
    public virtual Emp Supervisor { get; set; }
}
```

The problem that I'm having is that no matter how I map the relationships between these two classes, EF wants to relate the SupID on Activity to the EmpID on Emp instead of the SupID. Is it possible to do what I'm trying to do in EF without modifying the database?

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot do that.

Up to EF6 it's not possible to make a 1-to-many relation using an AK (alternate key) on the 1 side. The 1 side must always be the PK in the parent table.

MS has a site where you can vote for new EF features, and this is usually one of the top requested features: [Unique Constraint (i.e. Candidate Key) Support](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1050579-unique-constraint-i-e-candidate-key-support)

You can [vote for it here](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions), if you want.